# react-testing-library - fireEvent.select() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm currently running some tests for a project I'm working on, and am having trouble using [`fireEvent.select()`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/blob/master/src/index.js#L67) as a way to focus on an input field.

#### My test so far:

```
it('is not working :(', () => {
  const input = queryByPlaceholderText('blah');

  fireEvent.change(input, {
    target: {value: 'some text'},
  });

  expect(input).toHaveAttribute('value', 'some text');

  fireEvent.select(input); <-- issue here
});
```

The component I am testing has a dropdown menu that is only exposed when the input is focused on, but it seems like neither `fireEvent.change()` nor `fireEvent.select()` are focusing on the field. I know that `fireEvent.change()` changes the input value.

#### So far, I have tried:

- `fireEvent.click()`
- `fireEvent.focus()`
- `fireEvent.select()`
- `input.focus()`

but none of those options worked.

I need to be able to select an option in this dropdown menu to be able to properly test the component.

#### TL;DR

Is there a way to focus on an input field with RTL?

Comment: Did you try using `fireEvent.click()` ?

Comment: Yes, that would have been good to mention. I'll add it to my original post. So far I have tried `fireEvent.click()`, `input.focus()`, and `fireEvent.focus()`, none of which have worked.

Comment: Can you put a minimum reproducible example on codesandbox?

Comment: @Zach - did you get this to work? I'm struggling with a similar issue right now using React-Select.

Comment: @thejohnbackes did you get this working?
I'm struggling with react-dropdown

Comment: I had to use React-DOM to get this to work with React-Select

Comment: @ChristianSaiki I added an answer below

Answer (score 3):

In order to get this to work with React-Select, I had to use ReactDOM instead of `fireEvent`. Then I could test/run assertions with `react-testing-library` as normal.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';

export const openDropdown = ($container) => {
  // Opens the dropdown
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-find-dom-node
  selectOption(ReactDOM.findDOMNode($container).querySelector('.Select-arrow'));
};

export const selectOption = ($container) => {
  // Selects an option from the dropdown
  TestUtils.Simulate.mouseDown($container, { button: 0 });
};
```

```
    const $fooSelect = await waitForElement(() => app.getByTestId('foo-select'));
    openDropdown($fooSelect);
    const $fooElement = await waitForElement(() => app.getByText(fooFixture[0].name));

    selectOption($fooElement);

    await wait()
    // do stuff...
```